# CSxCC stage, series-shunt feedback, identify sign of feedback

Tags: transistors, amplifier, feedback, homework

[image]

MY ANALISIS
The stage is inverting x non inverting = non inverting.
Shunt sampling since it perturbs the output current, Series mixing. 
Thus if a positive input voltage is applied, the output is negative.
Thus the voltage applied on the source by the feedback network is negative and it increases Vgs

Thus feedback is positive.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Why inverting x non inverting gives you non-inverting?

Comment: you are feeding an inverted output voltage as input of a non inverted stage. The second stage has a voltage output with the same sign as the input.